# Is it possible to have multiple UIViews inside a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to set up a `UIPageViewController` that swipes through three very different views. I need to have a `UICollectionView`, a `UITableView`, then another `UICollectionView` with a different format. Can anyone clarify, whether this is possible or not? I have been searching for the last couple days and have not found a definitive answer. I am not asking for someone to solve this for me, I simply want to know if I should give up and just go with a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

From the UIPageViewController Class Reference:

```
A page view controller lets the user navigate between pages of content, 
where each page is managed by its own view controller object.
```

You need to have a viewController for each page. I recommend you read here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

Comment: Thanks everyone, accepted this one because it had the most detail.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can. The `UIPageViewController` is made to display different view controllers.

Try it for yourself, it's not that hard. You'll need to implement a `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` to return your different `UIViewControllers`, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can have different views inside a `UIPageViewController`. That is the first line in Apple documentation of `UIPageViewController`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

```
 A page view controller lets the user navigate between pages of content, 
where each page is managed by its own view controller object.
```

Below is method is used to set the view controllers to be displayed.

```
setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:
```

For tutorials/sample-code, you can go through below:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010135

http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Go through these links and then start coding your requirements. You will be good to go then.